# Proving pairwise independence of a set of hash functions

Tags: hash

A collection of hash functions $H=\{h:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^m\}$ is pairwise independent if for every $x_1 \neq x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $y_1, y_2 \in \{0,1\}^m$:

$$ \Pr_{h \leftarrow H}[h(x_1)=y_1 \wedge h(x_2)=y_2]=\frac{1}{2^{2m}} $$

Given a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ of size $2^n$ I've been able to prove for the set of hash functions:
$\{h_{a,b}: \mathbb{F}\to \mathbb{F}\}_{a,b \in \mathbb{F}}$ where: $h_{a,b}=ax+b$
that it is pairwise independent.

I am now asked to extend this for the case where the domain and range are not the same - - the former has size $2^n$ and the latter $2^m$.

I thought of the following as the extension, but I'm not sure whether it would work: choose $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}$. The idea is that I need to have an inverse in the field in order to uniquely solve for $a,b$ (e.g. for $ax_1+b=y_1$ I want to solve for $a,b$ uniquely by finding $a=(y_1-b)x_1^{-1}$ and similarly for $b$ (a system of two equations mod $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$) so that I get the aforementioned probability). A corollary would mean making sure $x_1, x_2$ are in the field, i.e. there are $a$ and $b$ such that $x_1=(y_1-b)a^{-1}$. Since $y_1 \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ then it would be sufficient that also $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}$.

I'm quite unsure whether this is correct. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of pairwise independence says something *for all* $x_1,x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$. So shouldn't the same condition also hold for all $x_1,x_2$ from a *subset* of $\{0,1\}^n$, too?

Comment: @Mikero I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mind clarifying please? As far as my proof goes, $x_1,x_2$ are arbitrary elements in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: I'm saying that there is not really anything to do if input length $<$ output length -- i.e., the input space can be viewed as a subset of the output space. In that case, the existing analysis just works.

Comment: @Mikero Yes, that's OK, but what about the case where input length > output length? The aforementioned solution should (unless I'm mistaken) capture both cases, no?

Comment: No, you need to do something else for input > output. But I'm not sure how much of a hint to give since I'm not sure whether this is homework.

Comment: @Mikero It is indeed homework so I would prefer a more instructive hint of how to think about this over a blatant solution, but I think I might have an idea why my current solution fails for the case input > output -- just as I needed $x_i \in \{0,1\}^m$ I also need $x_i$ to be **all** elements in $\{0,1\}^n$, whereas my solution is limited to a subset of them. If that's the case, I'm not sure how to 'expand' this to all of $\{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: @Mikero Think I got it for the case: input ($\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$) > output ($\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$): we still select $\{a,b\}$ from input, but the analysis goes as such:  If $(a,b)$ is a solution, w.l.g the solution with the smallest $a$ such that it is also an element in  $\mathbb{Z}^{2m}$, then there are $2^{n-m}$ additional solutions $(a_i, b)$ ($i \in 2^{n-m}$) - one for each multiple of $2^m$. Since the same goes for holding $a_i$ constant ($(a_i,b_j)$ where $j \in 2^{n-m}$) there are $2^{2(n-m)}$ solutions out of $2^{2n}$ $(a,b)$ pairs, yielding $\frac{2^{2(n-m)}}{2^{2n}}=2^{-2m}$. Correct?

Comment: What you describe sounds like $h(x) = ((ax+b) \bmod 2^{m}) \bmod 2^n$. If I've understood correctly then: (1) integers mod $2^n$ are not a field, so the pairwise independence analysis doesn't work (can't multiply by an inverse); (2) this is the same as $a (x \bmod 2^n) + b$ and so if $x, x'$ are congruent mod $2^n$ then they are a collision in $h$ (no matter what $a,b$ are).